# CORS not working even though OPTIONS returns HTTP 200

Tags: http, go, cors, go-chi

I am using chi and have setup cors as follows

```
func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(render.SetContentType(render.ContentTypeJSON))
    r.Use(Cors)

    r.Post("/auth/login", Login)
    r.Route("/ec2", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(Cors)
        r.Get("/", ListEc2)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
}
```

My `Cors` middleware

```
func Cors(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Allow-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Allow-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Allow-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Allow-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        log.Printf("Should set headers")

        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            log.Printf("Should return for OPTIONS")
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

In network tab it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Personally I prefer to use open source solutions rather than writting new on my own. Take look at:

https://github.com/rs/cors/blob/master/cors.go#L225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just mistyped the header names:

```
w.Header().Set("Allow-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                ^^^^^
```

Instead of *Allow-Control* there, you need *Access-Control*:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

…and same of course for the other three headers you’re setting there.